# text over image in bootstrap text div goes over width, how to align width of box to image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to align the background of .header to the same size as the image width, and so it scales with the image responsive.

Here it is on codepen: https://codepen.io/jggrs/pen/owKdvz?editors=1100

What I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR11i.jpg

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

   <div class="first-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
   </div>

   <div class="second-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
   </div>

   <div class="third-column col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="header">header</div>
   <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
   </div>

   </div> 
   </div>
```

CSS

```
    .first-column{background-color: #c0c0c0}
    .second-column{background-color: #808080}
    .third-column{background-color: #778899}

    .header{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: header position: absolute; is not the way to go when going responsive I think

Comment: yeah as Rienik said remove 'absolute' position from .header and you will be good to go

Comment: Thank you guys!! that worked....oh my god I've spent too much time on this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: [Relative absolute positioning](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

```css
.first-column{background-color: #c0c0c0}
.second-column{background-color: #808080}
.third-column{background-color: #778899}

.header {
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    float: bottom;
}

.col {
  position: relative
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">

     <div class="first-column col col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="header">header</div>
       <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
     </div>

     <div class="second-column col col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="header">header</div>
       <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
     </div>

     <div class="third-column col col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
       <div class="header">header</div>
       <img class="img-responsive" src="https://unsplash.it/500">
     </div>

   </div> 
 </div>
```